# SharePoint 2007 as iPad web app server

Tags: 2007, mobile, apple-ios

I'm faced with the problem that I need to get some dynamic reporting done on iPads. The only server available at the moment is a sharepoint 2007 server. As I don't have the tools or time to create a dedicated iPad application. The idea of creating an iPad web app seems the best solution at the time.

The thing I'm trying to figure out is whether it's possible to use Sharepoint 2007 as a webserver for iPad web-apps. Anybody out there who has experience getting this working?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I follow you on this one. You want to use SharePoint 2007 to host custom reports, built specifically for iPad, but where will you be pulling report data from, SQL or SharePoint?

If your data source is external to SharePoint, why waste time getting that data into SharePoint for hosting? If you mean, the server that hosts SharePoint 2007, why consider using the SharePoint platform at all?

Have a look at [Cordova](http://bit.ly/YLdstV), it allows you to build a normal HTML web site and porting it to your desired device as a native application.

Comment: I only have access to the Sharepoint part of the server. Sadly, the needs for our part of the organisation are not in line with the global needs. Due to our relative size, we're kinda stuck with these tools. 
At the moment, we use Excel and VBA to generate 2000 pdf files containing customer specific data which we send to our field people so while Sharepoint is the most unlikely of candidates as a hosting platform, it sounds better then our current process.  

Thanks for the tip, it should help in figuring out how to proceed.